# The procedure entry point av_buffer_create could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to open VS Code it gives me this error:
"The procedure entry point av_buffer_create could not be located in the dynamic link library A:\Applicazioni\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe."
I don't know what to do. Does anybody have a solution?

EDIT: The problem was solved by simply uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code. I was trying to avoid doing this because I worried it would have messed things up. Likely for me it didn't. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you uninstall and reinstall the vscode, it will be fixed.

Comment: I too thought that uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code would fix the problem, but that is something I was trying to avoid. I did everything that was said in the article but nothing worked.